# How to detect if Google Play Services is installed from Unity?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

Some devices do not have Google Play Services installed, so I can't use APIs like Google Play Game Services.  From Unity, how can I detect that Play Services is not installed so I have to skip calling GPGS?

I know I need to invoke [GoogleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(android.content.Context)), but I need to from C#.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the JNI support in Unity to invoke Java API calls from C#.  In this case the call to isGooglePlayServicesAvailable would look like:

```
 public bool IsPlayServicesAvailable()
        {
            const string GoogleApiAvailability_Classname = 
                "com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability";
            AndroidJavaClass clazz = 
                new AndroidJavaClass(GoogleApiAvailability_Classname);
            AndroidJavaObject obj = 
                clazz.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("getInstance");

            var androidJC = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
            var activity = androidJC.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");

            int value = obj.Call<int>("isGooglePlayServicesAvailable", activity);

            // result codes from https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult

            // 0 == success
            // 1 == service_missing
            // 2 == update service required
            // 3 == service disabled
            // 18 == service updating
            // 9 == service invalid
            return value == 0;
        }
```