# How to get Android Account in Unity without using Google Play Games

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, authentication

Hello I need to get the Android user profile even if the users don't have Google Play Games installed on their Android device. I found that there is Android AccountManager and AccountPicker but I couldn't find any info how to use it in Unity.

Comment: If you are asking how to authenticate a Google Account in the Unity Editor [check out this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47284852/google-play-sign-in-for-unity).

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Yes I need it to authenticate the user but without using the GP Games Services. I am using them for Google Sign In but I need to make guest authentication like in Call of Duty Mobile. If you choose guest it shows a popUp to select your Google Play email but they are not using Games Services and thus it is not needed to be installed on the user’s phone.

Comment: You can [check to see if Play Services is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32721499/how-to-detect-if-google-play-services-is-installed-from-unity) and if it is not, do not activate the Play Services functionality, then prompt them with your guest account login.